# gRPC linking takes too long after upgrading to version 1.54.0 from a two years older version

Tags: c++, grpc

Before the upgrade, linking at my app took few seconds for gRPc. Now it takes 3 minutes.
I don't know what was the version number of the older version, but I know it's two years older than 1.54.0 .
Did you also see something like that when upgrading between gRPC versions? Can you tell what's the reason for that?